# create tables using pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I am trying to create a table where the values for each column is read from a log file. I am trying this simple piece of code:

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{h1_error.log}\dataA
\pgfplotstableread{l2_error.log}\dataB

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index] 0}] {par1} {\dataA}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index] 1}] {par2} {\dataA}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\dataA}
\end{document}
```

where the log files look like 
h1_error.log=

```
<#N      H1 error
40  0.231438
#N       H1 error
40  -nan
#N       H1 error
40  0.231438
#N       H1 error
5   1.32218
#N       H1 error
5   1.60331
 >
```

and
l2_error.log=

```
<
#N       L2 error
40  0.00624957
#N       L2 error
40  0.00809222
#N       L2 error
40  0.00624957
#N       L2 error
5   0.246561
#N       L2 error
5   0.307461
>
```

but I keep getting,

> I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/copy column from table' and
>   I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

if I only use

```
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{h1_error.log}\dataA
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\dataA}
\end{document}
```

I get what I want

[image]

Anyone knows whats going on? thanks in advance.

Comment: Try typesetting the data first to see what got read in.  And use [string type].

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have edited the question, I guess now its clear.

Comment: They are column names

Answer (score 2):

I get no error from the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[header=has colnames]{
0  1
40 .23
40 nan
40 .23
5  1.32
5  1.6
}\dataA

\pgfplotstableread[header=has colnames]{
0  1
40 .23
40 nan
40 .23
5  1.32
5  1.6
}\dataB

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index]0}] {par1} {\dataA}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index]1}] {par2} {\dataA}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\dataA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I just copy and paste above MWE, I can't compile using TexMaker 4.5 :( and can't see any pdf :(

Comment: Using the above MWE, I keep getting [Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/table/copy/column fro
m table' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.] Anyone has an idea about what is going on? I am on Mac computer and compiling the tex file using Texmaker 4.5

Comment: You probably need to update your packages.